# How to access specific text from json data? [python]

Tags: python, json, api

I need to access the text attribute from this json data so i could end up having:

```
{'description': {'tags': ['outdoor', 'building', 'street', 'city', 'busy', 'people', 'filled', 'traffic', 'many', 'table', 'car', 'group', 'walking', 'bunch', 'crowded', 'large', 'night', 'light', 'standing', 'man', 'tall', 'umbrella', 'riding', 'sign', 'crowd'], 'captions': [{'text': 'a group of people on a city street filled with traffic at night', 'confidence': 0.8241405091548035}]}, 'requestId': '12fd327f-9b9c-4820-9feb-357a776211d3', 'metadata': {'width': 1826, 'height': 2436, 'format': 'Jpeg'}}
text = "The Text"
```

I Have tried doing parsed['captions']['text'] but this didnt work. Please let me know if you can help Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here. First, `captions` is under `description`, and second, `text` is a key of a dictionary inside a list (first and only item):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(parsed)
{'description': {'captions': [{'confidence': 0.8241405091548035,
                               'text': 'a group of people on a city street filled with traffic at night'}],
...
```

So, you could extract the `text` like this:

```
>>> parsed['description']['captions'][0]['text']
'a group of people on a city street filled with traffic at night'
```

---

Another option could be to use a 3rd-party library that simplifies traversing such JSON structures, for example [`plucky`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plucky/) (full disclosure: I'm the author). With `plucky`, you can say:

```
>>> from plucky import pluckable
>>> pluckable(parsed).description.captions.text
['a group of people on a city street filled with traffic at night']
```

and not worry about dictionaries inside lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python json library here, like below -

```
import json

your_json_string = "{'description': {'tags': ['outdoor', 'building', 'street', 'city', 'busy', 'people', 'filled', 'traffic', 'many', 'table', 'car', 'group', 'walking', 'bunch', 'crowded', 'large', 'night', 'light', 'standing', 'man', 'tall', 'umbrella', 'riding', 'sign', 'crowd'], 'captions': [{'text': 'a group of people on a city street filled with traffic at night', 'confidence': 0.8241405091548035}]}, 'requestId': '12fd327f-9b9c-4820-9feb-357a776211d3', 'metadata': {'width': 1826, 'height': 2436, 'format': 'Jpeg'}}"
data_dict = json.loads(your_json_string)
print(data_dict['description']['captions'][0]['text'])
```

Comment: This won't work since the string `your_json_string` is not strictly valid JSON.